# Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Package[ksh] is already declared in file

Tags: puppet

I have an issue in setting up ksh installation on a module where it fails saying its already declared in another module. can someone assist me on how can I fix this?

my code :

on a module called nessus:

class nessus::user {
group { 'nesscn':
ensure => 'present',
gid    => '7250',
}

```
package { 'ksh':
    ensure => installed,
}
```

code on oracle module:

class ig_oracle_server::oracle_package_deps {
if (versioncmp($::operatingsystemmajrelease, '5') == 0) {
package { [
'binutils',
'compat-libstdc++-33',
'gcc',
'gcc-c++',
'glibc',
'glibc-devel',
'ksh',
'libgcc',
'libstdc++',
'libstdc++-devel',
'libaio',
'libaio-devel',
'make',
'smartmontools',
'elfutils-libelf-devel',
]:
ensure => 'present',
}
}

I tried below declarations but nothing helps.

approach 1 :

if ! defined(Package['ksh']) {
package { 'ksh':
ensure => installed,
}
}

approach 2:

realize( Package[ 'ksh' ] )

Appreciate someone's early response!!

Thanks